# VBA Run-time error 450 from function returning a collection

Tags: vba

**Context:** I am writing a function which returns words/numbers present in a string which are enclosed by parenthesis.

**Example:** Calling `ExtractParenthesis("This {should} work. But {doesnt}.")` should return a collection containing two items, `should` and `doesnt`.

**Error:** The error I receive from the code below is

> Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property
>   assignment

It doesn't appear on a particular line and I just receive an error message with "OK" and "Help" as options.

**Code:**

```
Public Function ExtractParenthesis(strText As String) As Collection

    Dim i As Long
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Dim Matches As Object
    Dim Output As New Collection

    Set Output = Nothing
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RegExp.Pattern = "{(.*?)}"
    RegExp.Global = True

    Set Matches = RegExp.Execute(strText)

    For i = 0 To (Matches.count - 1)
        Output.Add Matches(i).submatches(0)
    Next i

    Set ExtractParenthesis = Output

End Function
```

Comment: Great question. Just add where exactly do you receive the error.

Comment: Change to Public Function ExtractParenthesis(strText As String) As object ,
while calling it do not forget to set it
dim test1 as collections;
set test1 = ExtractParenthesis("Test(and)tes")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly the way you want it for me:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myColl  As New Collection

    Set myColl = ExtractParenthesis("This {should} work. But {doesnt}.")

    Debug.Print myColl(1)
    Debug.Print myColl(2)

End Sub

Public Function ExtractParenthesis(strText As String) As Collection

    Dim i As Long
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Dim Matches As Object
    Dim Output As New Collection

    Set Output = Nothing
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RegExp.Pattern = "{(.*?)}"
    RegExp.Global = True

    Set Matches = RegExp.Execute(strText)

    For i = 0 To (Matches.Count - 1)
        Output.Add Matches(i).submatches(0)
    Next i

    Set ExtractParenthesis = Output

End Function
```

I receive "should" and "doesnt" on the immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). Probably you are not aware that you are returning a collection. It should be used with the `Set` keyword.

---

To run it from the immediate window, try like this:

```
?ExtractParenthesis("This {should} work. But {doesnt}.")(1)
?ExtractParenthesis("This {should} work. But {doesnt}.")(2)
```

Comment: I just want to add this worked by call it from another function/sub. Previously I was running it from the Immediate Window. Many thanks.

Comment: @BarryBlade - see the edit how to run it from the immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your comment to Vityatas answer you mean you want to run it as a worksheet function - *running it directly*

The changes I've made to your code will let you use it as a function:

In `A1:B1` this will work: `{=ExtractParenthesis("This {should} work. But {doesnt}.")}`
In `A1:A2` use it like this: `{=TRANSPOSE(ExtractParenthesis("This {should} work. But {doesnt}."))}`

*NB:* The curly brackets are added by Excel when you enter the formula using *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* rather than *Enter* on its own.

The one problem with the code is that you must select the correct number of cells first - if it should return three words, but you've only selected two then you'll only see the first two.

```
Public Function ExtractParenthesis(strText As String) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Dim Matches As Object
    Dim Output As Variant

    Set Output = Nothing
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RegExp.Pattern = "{(.*?)}"
    RegExp.Global = True

    Set Matches = RegExp.Execute(strText)

    ReDim Output(1 To Matches.Count)
    For i = 1 To (Matches.Count)
        Output(i) = Matches(i - 1).submatches(0)
    Next i

    ExtractParenthesis = Output

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Darren. Alas, no, I was trying to run it from another method but was calling it from the Immediate window whilst testing which seemed to screw things up.